# How to add a DropDownList into a Cell in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In the code below, I created a DropDownList, to insert in the TableCell cellA, which method can I use to add a DropDownList int a TableCell

```
        List<ListItem> items;
        items.Add(new ListItem("A1", "A1"));
        items.Add(new ListItem("A2", "A2"));
        items.Add(new ListItem("B1", "B1"));
        items.Add(new ListItem("B2", "B2"));
        items.Add(new ListItem("C1", "C1"));
        items.Add(new ListItem("C2", "C2"));

        DropDownList listA = new DropDownList();
        listA.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());

        TableCell cellA = new TableCell();
```

Comment: `cellA.Controls.Add(listA)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it to the control's control-collection, therefore use this code:

```
cellA.Controls.Add(listA);
```

However, you also have to add this cell to the [`TableRow.Cells`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablerow.cells%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), this row to  [`Table.Rows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table.rows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and this table to the page's control-collection (or to any other control in the page).